# PHP: Problem with filesize

Tags: php, file-upload, filesize

I need a little help here:

I get a file from an HTML upload form. And I have a "target" filename in $File.

When I do this:

```
copy($_FILES['binfile']['tmp_name'], $File);
echo '<hr>' . filesize($_FILES['binfile']['tmp_name']);
echo '<hr>' . filesize($File);
```

Everything works fine. I get the same number twice.

However when I delete the first call of *filesize()*, I get "0" (zero).

```
copy($_FILES['binfile']['tmp_name'], $File);
echo '<hr>' . filesize($File);
```

Any suggestions? What am I doing wrong? Why do I need to get the filesize of the "original" file before I can get the size of the copy?

(That's actually what it is: I need to call the *filesize()* for the original file. Neither *sleep()* nor calling *filesize()* of another file helps.)

System:

- Apache 2.0
- PHP 5.2.6
- Debian Linux (Lenny)

Comment: Don’t use `copy`; use `move_uploaded_file` instead.

Comment: @Gumbo: Cool. Didn't know that function existed. Seems to solve my problem, too.

Comment: Have you checked for similar behavior on another setup?

Comment: @zaf I tried to do copy() and a following filesize() with files that already exist in the system. No problem there. Didn't try on another server, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How big is this file? You are doing a copy and then stating the file straight away. Could this be the problem?

Does the builtin move_uploaded_file() function give the same behavior?

Comment: It's just 300kb. It doesn't seem to be a timing problem, because "sleep" doesn't help.

Comment: That is strange. It would interesting to know whats going on here.

Comment: Accepted this answer, because "move_uploaded_file" solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
copy($_FILES['binfile']['tmp_name'], $File);
clearstatcache();
$filesize = $_FILES['binfile']['size'];
echo '<hr>' . $filesize;
```

Comment: Just believe me that it has a value - and it has another value than tmp_name, because obviously I don't want to copy the file to itself.

Comment: Because this code is just what I condensed my problem to. I use a library that needs the filename to have an ".jpg" extension.

Comment: clearstatcache() seems to help. I wouldn't be able to use $_FILES...['size'] though, because - as I said - there is another library and that library uses the filesize somewhere deep inside.

Comment: Well, you could create a function that could sleep until the file_exist returns true.  If the `file_exists($File)` function returns true, than do `filesize($File);`

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
copy($_FILES['binfile']['tmp_name'], $File);

clearstatcache();
while (empty(filesize($File)))
    sleep(2);

echo '<hr>' . filesize($File);
```

OR try this:

```
copy($_FILES['binfile']['tmp_name'], $File);

clearstatcache();
while (!file_exists($File))
    sleep(2);

echo '<hr>' . filesize($File);
```